# Finding the skewed bounds of a pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css

***Edit** So A Haworth's answer below was correct, except it needs to be radians rather than degrees passed to `tan`, so:

`x = tan(12deg) * h/2`

becomes:

```
  const radians = 12 * (Math.PI/180);
  const x = Math.tan(radians) * h/2;
```

Taking a width and height of 716.4 and 789.4 lead to a tan of `0.212` and an offset of `167.79`. But this is still fractionally off from the correct answer from what I can tell - which is making a fairly noticeable difference.

---

**Original question**

Am trying to find the bottom right coordinates of the white pseudo element. It's set at 3/5's of the full screen width. The red progress bar has its `left` set to 2/5's. So I'm basically looking for the value of x in the image below, if not the adjusted value directly.

The skew is `transform: skewX(12deg)`, but applied with tailwind. No doubt there's a mathmatical way of calculating it, but I've no idea :D

Thanks!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/JjBGbqW?editors=1011)

[image]

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
const progress = document.querySelector('.progress');
const root = document.documentElement;

setLeft();

window.addEventListener('resize', setLeft);

function setLeft() {
  const bounds = content.getBoundingClientRect()
  const start = bounds.right/5 * 3;
  root.style.setProperty('--pseudo-left', `${start}px`)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --pseudo-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative bg-red-500">
  <div class="header fixed bg-slate-600 h-[10]">hello</div>
  <!-- First section -->
  <div class="relative mt-[10rem] h-4/5 w-full bg-white">
    
  <!-- Content Wrapper -->
  <div class="content relative h-full w-full bg-white 
                before:block before:absolute before:bg-white 
                before:w-3/5 before:h-full before:border-primary 
                before:border-r-8 before:-skew-x-12 before:z-20">
  <div class="progress absolute bottom-0 left-[var(--pseudo-left)] w-2/5 h-4 bg-red-500 border-l-4 border-red-500 z-30"></div>

  <img class="h-full w-4/5 ml-auto object-cover lg:h-full brightness-[45%] grayscale" src="https://www.ispo.com/sites/default/files/styles/teaser_module_one_third/public/b/76/39/76398068-imageData.jpg?h=8f756172&itok=TjFVRx73" alt="">

      <!-- Hero Content -->
      <div class="absolute mx-auto top-1/2 -translate-y-[58%] w-1/2 text-primary z-20">

        <div class="w-full px-12">
          <div class=" md:max-w-3xl lg:col-span-6 text-left">
            <h1>
              <span class="block mt-2 text-primary font-semibold">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
              </span>
            </h1>
            <p class="mt-3 text-base text-gray-500 sm:mt-5 sm:text-xl lg:text-lg xl:text-2xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, voluptatibus nostrum quas autem cupiditate accusamus? </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the positioning along the x axis of the skewed element is if you want to find the x in your image. Find the height (h) and then x = tan(12deg) * h/2 as you are skewing about the mid point.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth - thanks for the response, that's definitely what I'm after, but is there any chance you can take a quick look at my pen again please? I've implemented what you've said, and tried to use it, but it's not moving the element by the correct amount!